# Change <body> background image on <div> hover

Tags: html, css

So let's say I have a black/white background-image on the body tag, and I want it to switch to a *background-image* image of a city skyline while hovering over div id="1", and a background-image of the same skyline at night while hovering over div id="2". How would I go about that?

I have some html/css written for this already, as well as 'decent' python knowledge, but no experience with scripting languages such as javascript. I prefer not to copy large snippets of code, as I'm new and want to learn.

Here's what I have so far:

```
/*css*/

#bg{background:url('a');
}

#header{
  position:absolute;
  border:double 30pt;
  width:95%;
  height:15%;
}

#header img{height:120px;
}

#header img:hover{
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

#allies{
  border:double 30pt;
  position:relative;
  width:45%;
  top:250px;

}

#allies:hover ~ #bg{background:url('b');
}

#enemies{
  border:double 30pt;
  position:relative;
  width:45%;
  /*top:55px;*/
  top:-67px;
  left:967px;
}

#enemies:hover ~ #bg{background:url('c')
}

div img{
  width:120px;
  height:100px;
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AE</title>
    <link href="AE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body id="bg">
    <div id="header">
      <a href="index.htm">
        <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/home-5-xxl.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="allies">
        <img src="http://fontmeme.com/permalink/170203/949c0c2c2c0c34c044b9b45585717a70.png">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="enemies">
        <img src="http://fontmeme.com/permalink/170203/e8d4db59e876e5c94bd8f072137e33e2.png">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Python is a scripting language, too.

Comment: You can use javascript to add event listeners (mouseEnter, mouseLeave) on your divs. Then inside these listeners, dynamicaly change the background. An easy way would be to use jQuery even if I don't like it that much, it's an easy way to handle theses events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what you want, use Jquery :

Jquery :

```
$( "#allies" ).hover(function() {
    $('body').css("background", "url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/14/20/24/water-103817_960_720.jpg");
});

$( "#enemies" ).hover(function() {
    $('body').css("background", "url(http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/fire/fire-02.jpg");
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fg8n57sy/)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Comment: Nice ! Don't forget to mark this as answer in order to help people to find what they are looking for. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this by css. Use jQuery hover() function. Inside function you can either use css() fuction or (better) addClass()/removeClass() which you define in your css file. https://api.jquery.com/hover/

js:

```
$('#allies').hover(function() {
    $('#bg').addClass('newBg1');
}, function() {
    $('#bg').removeClass('newBg1');
});
$('#enemies').hover(function() {
    $('#bg').addClass('newBg2');
}, function() {
    $('#bg').removeClass('newBg2');
});
```

css:

```
.newBg1 {
    background-image: #your url;
}
.newBg2 {
    background-image: #your url;
}
```